# How can I connect Jet Brains DataGrip to an Elasticsearch instance?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, datagrip

I have Jet Brains DataGrip, I also have an elasticsearch instance running locally in docker exposed on a known port via the tcp protocol.

How can I connect DataGrip to my elasticsearch instance?

DataGrip doesn't list it as a type of database to be connected to, nor does googling seem to reveal anything useful to me.

Comment: You can't connect to an Elasticsearch instance via Datagrip. It doesn't have that feature. You can try ElasticHQ or elasticsearch-gui for this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you expect DataGrip to do that Kibana can't?

Comment: Not have to context switch out of DataGrip just for ES, to export data, and to not have to wait on a clunky slow JS web interface. Kibana is just friction and a lack of keyboard shortcuts for me.

Comment: You can try [Elasticsearch Plugin](https://github.com/AntonShuvaev/elasticsearch4idea) for Intellij IDEA (DataGrip). It uses REST API, not a JDBC. The main functionality: - Connecting to cluster with Basic Auth, SSL - Viewing main information about clusters and indices - Convenient sending requests with a set of commonly used requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible since Elasticsearch has JDBC-driver: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/jdbc-client

You should create a custom-driver based connection in DataGrip.

Then you create a new Driver on the 'Data Sources and Drivers' dialog. Click on the '+' button on the upper left corner.  Choose Driver.

[image]

Complete the new driver's options. Use downloaded JDBC drivers there.

Now you can create a new Data Source based on this new driver. Click on '+' button on the upper left corner of the 'Data Sources and Driver' and choose your new driver.

Complete the Data Source options. And finally choose which schemas you want to access on the 'Schemas' tab.

Comment: It works with ES 7.2. But you need to have a Platinum subscription to be able to use JDBC driver. More info about ES subscriptions: https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

Comment: There seems to be a JDBC driver from cdata.com, it does look like it very well could be a different JDBC implementation, but it's not free, there's a trial and full version, and without an e-mailed price quote it costs $1,999 for an annual subscription to all the drivers in the suite. https://www.cdata.com/drivers/elasticsearch/jdbc/

Answer (score 1):

You can install [ElasticSearch](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14512-elasticsearch) plugin in DataGrip. It is not free, but you can try it as a trial version or install it using your DataGrip license. To create a connection you can follow [this link](https://www.intellij-elasticsearch.com/docs/features/connection/).

Comment: I can recommend that plugin.  The price is not that high (around $30 per year) and the tool is really helpful. I do not want to miss it...